# Sprint MVC 3 REST - Always return JSON object

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to set my REST service built with Spring 3 MVC to always return a JSON object, even when responding with things like a HTTP 406. I've tried setting a custom error handler in my controller, but it still doesn't handle 406 errors, so I still get back the default tomcat 406 html page in my response. Is there a better way to do this?

My goal is to always return a JSON object (instead of the tomcat error pages), no matter if it's an exception I throw or an exception thrown by the framework (like a HTTP 406).

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    public void handleError(HttpServletResponse resp, HttpServletRequest req, 
            Throwable tr) throws Throwable {

        //TODO this isn't working because valid exceptions like 406 don't have
        //this annotation
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(tr.getClass(), 
                ResponseStatus.class) != null) {
            throw tr;
        }

        //Do some stuff...get stuff out of Throwable object
        ResponseEntity<MyCustomErrorType> respEntity = 
            new ResponseEntity<MyCustomErrorType>(tr);
        ...

        new ObjectMapper().getFactory().createJsonGenerator(resp.getOutputStream())
            .writeObject(respEntity);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try setting the accept header to application/json

Comment: I want to handle the case when the accept header is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

HI you can handle All the Exception throw by rest Using ExceptionMapper.
This is very good way to handle your custom Exception.
i followed the post :http://entityclass.in/rest/exceptionhandling.htm

Comment: This article targets JAX-RS. I am using Spring MVC, not Jersey / JAX-RS. Will this work with Spring?

Comment: HI i am not sure about this , it will work with spring or not.Will be update on  on post very soon

Answer (score 0):

For my project it worked different when throwing a Custom Exception than when Spring throws one of its MissingPathVariableException, etc...

So at the end we found an approach that satisfied both Custom and Spring Exceptions to unify the JSON message we were returning in every case.

1. Created a ControllerAdvice and copy logic from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler (Spring class). This will override the behavior for the predefined exceptions:

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice
   public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

   private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   @ExceptionHandler(value = {
           org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class,
           HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class, HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class,
           HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class, MissingPathVariableException.class,
           MissingServletRequestParameterException.class, ServletRequestBindingException.class,
           ConversionNotSupportedException.class, TypeMismatchException.class, HttpMessageNotReadableException.class,
           HttpMessageNotWritableException.class, MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
           MissingServletRequestPartException.class, BindException.class, NoHandlerFoundException.class,
           AsyncRequestTimeoutException.class })
   protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
   ```

This controller returns a new ResponseEntity and disables the Tomcat error page for these Exceptions.

2. In the same Controller, we created another method for our Custom Exceptions:

   ```
   @ExceptionHandler(value = { BadRequestException.class, 
   InternalServerErrorException.class,
           NotAllowedException.class, NotFoundException.class, 
   ServiceUnavailableException.class,
           UnauthorizedException.class, ConflictException.class })
   public void handleCustomExceptions(HttpServletRequest request, 
   HttpServletResponse response, Exception ex)
           throws IOException {

       // here do your logic so that at the end you modify the response
       response.setStatus(errorCode);
       response.getWriter().print(YOUR JSON OBJECT GOES HERE));

   }
   ```